# Iterating Values in Grid and Card in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui, react-hooks

I wanted to achieve as less code as possible so I implementing a reusable component in my app.
My problem is how can I iterate the columns and rows in `Grid`, `Card` and `Table`. What will be the best solution to this?

Pls check my codesandbox

[Click Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-h9ji8?file=/demo.js)

**Expected Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
  <Grid container spacing={2}>
    {rows.map((row, index) => (
      <Grid item md={4} sm={6} xs={12} key={index}>
        <CardComponent columns={columns} rows={row} />
      </Grid>
    ))}
  </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it without changing your initial code too much

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-nk293

demo.js

```js
  const columns = [
    { headerName: "ID", field: "id" },
    { headerName: "Request", field: "request" }
  ];
```

card.js

```
                <TableCell variant="body">{row[column.field]}</TableCell>
```

It's "similar" to [material-table's API](https://material-table.com/#/docs/get-started)

Comment: Thanks for this. What if i wanted to add a `<Button>` and i have added also a variable called 'dontDisplay` which i dont want to display.  Pls check this codesandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-h9ji8?file=/demo.js

Comment: You change the structure of my code to a better one. Thank you

Comment: So this `dontDisplay` is not a boolean, it's a string, what is it supposed to hide?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Pls disregard the `dontDisplay`. Just how can i add the `<Button>` with the `id` there? Its outside the iteration, right? You may restructure my code by the way

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-xvjjy
You can access the id right there because it's in the row, hope that helps :)

Comment: You are not stupid dude, you're welcome! glad to help ^^

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer **without** changing columns and row structure:

```js
<TableRow>
    <TableCell variant="head">{column.headerName}</TableCell>
    
    <TableCell variant="body">
            {rows[Object.keys(rows)[index]]}
    </TableCell>
</TableRow>
```